# Asignar valores al select

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

Tengo las clases Brand, Blend, Flavor y Drink. Sabor tiene una Marca y una Mezcla. Bebida se compone de un Sabor y otros campos:

```
public class Brand{
  public int BrandId{ get; set; }
  public string Name{ get; set; }
  public ICollection<Flavor> Flavors { get; set; }
}

public class Blend{
  public int BlendId{ get; set; }
  public string Name{ get; set; }
  public ICollection<Flavor> Flavors { get; set; }
}

public class Flavor{
  public int FlavorId{ get; set; }
  public int BrandId{ get; set; }
  public Brand Brand{ get; set; }
  public int BlendId{ get; set; }
  public Blend Blend{ get; set; }
}

public class Drink{
  public int DrinkId{ get; set; }
  public int FlavorId{ get; set; }
  public Flavor Flavor{ get; set; }
}
```

Necesito que al crear una bebida nueva (Views/Drink/Create.cshtml) el usuario seleccione un sabor a manera de string (Coca-Cola Vainilla) y no por su Id. En el caso de crear un nuevo sabor, por ejemplo, se puede enviar Text y Value de cada Marca al  del  por medio de:

```
ViewData["BrandId"] = new SelectList(_context.Brands, "BrandId", "Name");
```

pero en este caso se requiere accesar al campo Name de dos instancias ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas seleccionar mas de una opcion de la lista para formar el sabor usarias en el html un listbox

```
@Html.ListBox("BrandId", ViewBag.BrandList as MultiSelectList)
```

pero usa en la view

```
ViewBag.BrandList = new MultiSelectList(_context.Brands, "BrandId", "Name");
```

del articulo

[Using the DropDownList Helper with ASP.NET MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

analiza el titulo "Creating a Multiple Section Select Element"

**>>mi necesidad en este momento es poder seleccionar un solo Flavor, un string compuesto por Brand.Name + Blend.Name**

En ese caso podrias definir una propiedad en la clase Flavor que arme este cadena y puedas usarla en el select

```
public class Flavor
{
  public int FlavorId{ get; set; }
  public int BrandId{ get; set; }
  public Brand Brand{ get; set; }
  public int BlendId{ get; set; }
  public Blend Blend{ get; set; }

  public string FullName
  {
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Brand.Name, this.Blend.Name);}
  }
}
```

entonces usarias

```
ViewBag.FlavorList = new SelectList(_context.Flavors, "FlavorId", "FullName");
```

Como verás, se define el FullName como texto para mostrar en la lista de Flavors

Comment: Gracias pero en mi necesidad en este momento es poder seleccionar un solo _Flavor_, un string compuesto por Brand.Name + Blend.Name. Mediante código puedo usar alguno de los dos y obtener un un select con varias Marcas Pepsi, por ejemplo, pero cuando intento unir los dos strings de una u otra forma, lanza error o el select se rellena con strings.empty. También intenté crear un nuevo campo Name para Flavor que contuviera esos dos strings pero solo ubtuve _NullReferenceExceptions_ haciendolo de distintas formas

Comment: un error de null reference hace referencia a que no estas asignando la instancia de la clase. Deberias validar como cargas los datos del objetos Flavor, porque parece ser que no instancias las clases Brand y Blend sino que solo asignas los id. Si usas Entity Framework recuerda hacer uso del Include() para especificar que cargue estas propiedades relacionadas

Comment: No me gusta, ni parece solución pero funciona cargando esa lista en una variable detro del IActionResult Create( ): `(from item in _context.Flavors select new SelectListItem(){ Text= x, Value= y }).ToList();`